# Excel Word form creation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I want to setup a click option or something that will add the time to a new line and let me add a line of text like an event log. For example:

```
12:05pm check camera
3:30pm confirmed order
```

I don't know how to go about creating it easily I don't care on the program used

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Using word you can just click on Insert Tab, click on Date & Time and choose the format of the time, repeat for each new time

Comment: I wasn't asking for a completed copy just an idea of how to do the time stamp thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the timestamp formula once a time to whole column/range. Go through below url this could help you:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/01/08/timestamps-excel-formula-help/